# JTable won't listen to Doubleclicks

Tags: java, swing, jtable, double-click, mouselistener

I´m trying to  implement an undo (and redo) function for an editable `JTable` with the default components. The `JTable` has an extra class to specify its properties called `SpecifiedJTable`.

To do so I wanted to grab the moment when a cell is doubleclicked (i.e. the moment when a cell is chosen/marked to be edited) to push the information in the cell and its coordinates onto the stack.

This should be done by a `MouseListener` ...at least that was my idea.
I tried this (standing in the constructor of my `SpecifiedJTable` class)

```
class JTableSpecified extends JTable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int c; // the currently selected column
    private int r; // the currently selected row

    public JTableSpecified(String[][] obj, String[] columnNames) {
        super(obj, columnNames); // constructs the real table
        // makes that you can only select one row at a time
        this.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        // makes that columns are not squeezed
        this.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        // forbids to rearrange the columns
        getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        // adds action listener
        this.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
                r = getSelectedRow();
                c = getSelectedColumn();
                // get the String at row r and column c
                String s = (String) getValueAt(r, c);
                if (jobDisplayed) jobSwitch(c, s);
                else resSwitch(c, s);
            }
        });    
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    System.out.println("test");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but somehow the clickCounter doesn´t want to reach anything that´s higher than 1.

I am glad about any answer and help. Thanks.

Comment: In general, that should work.  I use something like that in my own code.  It is possible that there is some other mouse listener registered on your table which is consuming some mouse events and preventing them from being propagated to your listener.

Comment: Can you correct the code? As the way it is not it would not compile. Also please past more related code preferably [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: first of all, thanks to your answers. the extended code is now in the question.       @user1442870 could you imagine which one this is and even more important: do you have something in mind to "stop" the other listeners consuming the mouse events? at least the tablemodelListener is not the problem. i tried deactivating  it and the mouseListener didn´t react after all.

Comment: *"the extended code is.."* ..not an SSCCE.  Please read the content of the links offered.

Comment: Although I do use a similar double-click mouse listener on some of my own JTables, I have realized that I'm only doing that on non-editable tables.  When the table is editable, the table UI will be consuming some of those mouse events.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are experiencing is related to use of `mouseClicked()` rather than using `mousePressed()`. In this case it appears to be very hard to increase the click counter, yet still it is possible. It took me lots of clicking and also mouse movement to increase the click counter over 1. You could try it by yourself, in your code. To get the counter over 1 you need to go crazy on the mouse by pressing & releasing fast while moving the mouse from cell to cell at the same time (or maybe I was just luckily clicking between the cells?).

As you can see in this fully working sample, made from your code, two mouse presses, using the `mousePressed()` method are being detected just fine.

```
public class JTableSpecified extends JTable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JTableSpecified(String[][] obj, String[] columnNames) {
        super(obj, columnNames); // constructs the real table
        // makes that you can only select one row at a time
        this.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        // makes that columns are not squeezed
        this.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        // forbids to rearrange the columns
        getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
        // adds action listener
        this.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
            @Override
            public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            }
       });        
        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    System.out.println("test");
                }
                System.out.println("e.getClickCount() = " + e.getClickCount());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.add(new JTableSpecified(new String[][]{{"oi", "oi2"}, {"oi3", "oi4"}}, new String[]{"Col1", "Col2"}));
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setContentPane(panel);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Conclusion:** Maybe you in fact want to use the `mousePressed()` method?

Comment: yeah thanks a lot Boro. =) it really works with mousePressed(). Quite funny to see that it was such a "simple" solution I was searching for all the time. After several tests it seems to deliver the perfect result for my application, without any unwanted events. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The BasicTableUI is responding to the double-click by going into an edit mode on the cell that was double-clicked.  It does lots of complicated stuff, part of which involves creating a JTextField (or other component) to allow the data to be edited, and then preventing the mouse click event from propagating any further.

If your table, or that table cell, is not editable, you can easily capture mouse events with click count 2, 3, 4, ....  But since you want your table to be editable, you need a different approach.

One idea would be to override JTable.[editCellAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#editCellAt%28int,%20int,%20java.util.EventObject%29)

A better idea is to forget about messing with the JTable and instead listen for data changes on the table model itself.

Answer (score 1):

This answer extends Boro´s answer.
To catch every case that enables the user to edit the table I will also need to add a KeyListener for F2 (which has the same effect as double clicking onto a cell) and disable the automatic cell editing by pressing any key. 
I just added it to the constructor right behind the mouseListener (see above)

> // forbids the editing by striking a key
> this.putClientProperty("JTable.autoStartsEdit", Boolean.FALSE);
>
> // keyListener to react on pressing F2 (key code 113)
> this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
>
> > public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
> >
> > > if (e.getKeyCode() == 113) System.out.println("test");
> > > }
> > > });

Comment: +1 yea I like it. I always like when people enable editing with `F2`- the 'standard' key for editing.

Answer (score -1):

the error in the code is that the mouseClicked method is called as soon as the first click takes place. when a double click takes place the mouseClicked method is called again. you can place a static variable (or a class variable) for the earlier click event storing the time (using the e.getWhen() method).
Check for the time difference and if it's small enough, execute your actions (I'd suggest calling a doubleClick method).

you may have to implement mouse listener in your class JTableSpecified since a static variable might not be placed in your existing code.

Comment: hm i guess this not a real solution for my problem :/ because when you implement this you can click onto two different cells and it is also fired because the counter is at 2. maybe i could put this listener to each cell... is there a way do do this? or maybe there is a even better way without a mouselistener to detect the moment of selection.

Comment: yes u can check the position of the mouseEvent by the getPosition method. I didn't this was required because if the time difference is as low as 500ms, its not possible to click, move and click again all in 500ms. But if you want u can make 2 variables and check for both conditions. After all, double click is defined as two quick successive clicks without moving the mouse.