# mouse double click is not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

I have written this java code to detect the double click of left button on mouse, but this code is not working please help.

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class B extends MouseAdapter {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Object rows[][] = new Object[5][3];
    String colums[] = {"A","B","C"};
    JTable table = new JTable(rows,colums);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new B();
    }

    B() {
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        table.addMouseListener(this);
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent clicked) {
        if(clicked.getSource()==table && clicked.getButton()==1 && clicked.getClickCount()==2)
            System.out.println("Left Double Click");
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working?

Comment: I suppose "Left Double Click" is not appearing

Comment: You're example won't compile

Comment: possible duplicate of [JTable won't listen to Doubleclicks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105133/jtable-wont-listen-to-doubleclicks)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your example won't compile
2. You should be using `SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(clicked)` instead of `clicked.getButton()==1`
3. The table may be consuming the `MouseEvent` and installing the cell editor before your `MouseListener` is notified.
4. If you use `table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);` you can double click outside of the rows/columns successfully

You can change the table's `CellEditor`s to ignore the `MouseEvent` (or change the number of clicks required), this will allow you `MouseListener` to pick up the double clicks, but will also increase your work load, as you will need to supply a `CellEditor` for each column `Class` type

```
    TableCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField(10)) {

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
            boolean editable = false;
            if (!(anEvent instanceof MouseEvent)) {
                editable = super.isCellEditable(anEvent);
            }
            return editable;
        }

    };

    table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, editor);
```

Without more context, is difficult to know what else to suggest